# document.getElementById('id').innerHTML="some value" changes don't reflect

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, innerhtml

I have the below mentioned code, the changes made by innerHTML don't reflect in the browser

```
<body>

<script TYPE="text/javascript">
    function change(){
        document.getElementById("op").innerHTML="this works!";
        prompt(document.getElementById("op").innerHTML);
    }
</script>

<form onSubmit="change()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="a1">This</td>
           <td id="a2"><input type="text" id="t1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

// Output

```
    <table>
        <tr><td id="op"></td></tr>
    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

The changes do take place, as shown by prompt, but are not reflected on the page.

Comment: The page will be updated once your code finished executing. http://jsfiddle.net/8gq155ap/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k76tadte/1/

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is single threaded. The browser won't run a repaint event until the function that assigned the value to `innerHTML` is finished.

That function won't be finished until the prompt (which is a blocking function) is cleared.

At that point, since it was trigged by a submit button, the form will be immediately submitted and a new page will be loaded (which will have the content of the table cell back in the original state).

Cancel the default event for the form.

90s style:

```
function change()
{
  document.getElementById("op").innerHTML="this works!";
  prompt(document.getElementById("op").innerHTML);
  return false;
}

onSubmit="return change()">
```

Modern style:

```
function change(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("op").innerHTML="this works!";
  prompt(document.getElementById("op").innerHTML);
}
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", change);
```

Comment: This is maybe true in Firefox, but in Chrome (just tested), it does trigger a repaint as the thread is paused by `prompt` (with/without `preventDefault`)